# JMS/ActiveMQ MessageConsumer.recieve() not returning

Tags: java, azure, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have a Java application that uses what I believe to be fairly boiler plate JMS code to connect to and receive messages from an ActiveMQ server.

```
this.consumerFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(this.ingestItemBrokerUrl);
this.consumerConnection = this.consumerFactory.createConnection();
this.consumerConnection.start();
this.consumerSession = this.consumerConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
this.consumerDestination = this.consumerSession.createTopic(getIngestItemDestinationName());
this.consumer = this.consumerSession.createConsumer(this.consumerDestination);
```

My application calls `MessageConsumer.receive()` in a loop (until the connection is closed) to process messages as they arrive in an ActiveMQ topic:

```
message = this.consumer.receive();
```

**Here's the mystery:**

When I connect to an ActiveMQ server running on localhost, this works as expected.  But when I connect to an ActiveMQ server running on a azure cloud machine (loaded with Bitnami's ActiveMQ stack), the `receive()` call blocks indefinitely, even though I can see from the AMQ admin console that my client has connected and dequeued messages.

Why would I be seeing different behavior when switching from local to a remote server?  How can I further troubleshoot?

My cloud activemq.xml config file is below:

```
<beans xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd   http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
 <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES"/>
 <property name="password" value="**REDACTED**"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor"/>
  <property name="location" value="file:${activemq.conf}/credentials-enc.properties"/>
</bean>

<!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
<bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery" lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
</bean>

<!--
    The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
-->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
    <plugins>
        <!--simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
            <users>
                <authenticationUser username="${activemq.username}" password="${activemq.password}" groups="admins"/>
            </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin-->

        <!-- if not already set, set ttl to 1 minutes -->
        <timeStampingBrokerPlugin zeroExpirationOverride="60000"/>

    </plugins>

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic="&gt;" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
              <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                <vmCursor/>
              </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
            </policyEntry>
            <policyEntry queue="&gt;" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
              <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                   For more information, see:

                   http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

              <pendingQueuePolicy>
                <vmQueueCursor/>
              </pendingQueuePolicy>
              -->
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>


    <!--
        The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
        JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
        the JVM. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
    -->
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <!--
        Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
        mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
        For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
    -->
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>


      <!--
        The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
        use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:
        http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        If using ActiveMQ embedded - the following limits could safely be used:

    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>
    -->
      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <!--
        The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
        clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
    -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>


        <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;trace=true&amp;needClientAuth=true"/>
    </transportConnectors>

                    <!-- SSL Configuration Context -->
            <sslContext>
               <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/amq-server.ks"
                           keyStorePassword="**REDACTED**"
                                       trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/amq-server.ts"
                   trustStorePassword="**REDACTED**" />
            </sslContext>


</broker>

<!--
    Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
    The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

    Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
-->
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans><!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Comment: receive method is designed to block indefinitely until a message is received this is normal, have you sent a message to the topic when the consumer is running without consuming it and in this case receive method not return ? The config in cloud is different ? Can you post AMQ cloud config

Comment: I understand that `receive()` is supposed to block until a message arrives.  Using locahost, it blocks until I send a message.  Using the cloud AMQ, it blocks even after I send a message.

Comment: Can you post xml config of cloud AMQ

Comment: Added cloud activemq.xml config.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by using this as the destination name `this.consumerDestination = this.consumerSession.createTopic(getIngestItemDestinationName() + "?consumer.prefetchSize=1");`

or call

```
consumerFactory.getPrefetchPolicy().setTopicPrefetch(1);
```

Try with message listener

```
    MessageListener listner = new MessageListener() {
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            try {
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    System.out.println("Received message"
                            + textMessage.getText() + "'");
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                System.out.println("Caught:" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    consumer.setMessageListener(listner);
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion.  Same result:  recieve() never returns.

Comment: Second suggestion not possible.  My consumerFactory doesn't have `getPrefetchPolicy` method.

Comment: Your cloud version is 4.x ?

Comment: ActiveMQ version 5.14.1 on the cloud machine.  v5.14.0 on local host.

Comment: I added the suggested message listener.  ( I had to remove my receive call for this to not throw exceptions) The new listener code never gets called.

Comment: Sorry if the question is so easy because the problem you have is strange but to verify that you start the consumer and only after that when his receive method is blocked you send a message to the same topic on the same host. If you have done that in this order i don't know if the suspect is the destinationPolicy and the vmCursor because i never used it and i don't see anything else which can causes your problem.

Comment: Rebooting the cloud server fixed it.  Go figure.  :(

Comment: I hope that the problem will not come back after some time, as i see in doc `VM Cursor
The VM Cursor is how ActiveMQ 4.x works: references to a message are held in memory, and passed to the dispatch queue when needed. This can be very fast, but also has the downside of ** not being able to handle very slow consumers or consumers that have been inactive for a long**`